# Switches for PCB: Mounting and hole questions

Tags: pcb-design

I'm designing a pcb board and encountered a problem for switches. Is it common to follow the schematic and create square holes for mounting the switches?

[image: Switch pic]

[image: PCB mounting schematic]

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Evidently, you do not need to make square holes, these are just dimensions that *whatever you use* have to respect. By "whatever you use" I mean most likely round drilled holes or oblong machined ones.

Comment: For holes that size, I'd use round holes with the diameter just larger than the diagonal of the square.

Comment: What I want to know is, where did the switch vendor expect you to get a square drill bit? (Or did they expect this part to be used only on punched boards?)

Comment: @ThePhoton Drilled slots and square holes are things you can specify. They use many overlapping drill holes to form the shape.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, If that's what they meant to specify, they should have given a corner radius.

Comment: @ThePhoton It's a pretty crappy spec. The most recent encoder footprint I did used a drilled slot. It works pretty well. If you don't get the location fairly close the snap-in doesn't work properly. A bit surprising, that's Alpha (Taiwan) which is a pretty major mfr.

Comment: @ThePhoton drilling square holes [is actually a thing](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DrillingASquareHole/), counterintuitive but true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this part to properly be mounted to the PCB, it needs to have holes slightly bigger than the pin sizes.  In the datasheet, there is always a section that shows the required hole sizes as well as the measurements for each pin.

The two squares holes do not necessary need to be squared.  They can be round holes.  Round holes are the most common type of holes on a PCB for through holes components.  Just make sure the diameter of the round hole exceeds the diagonal length of the square and you should be fine.  You will require a bit more solder to fully mount the switch but it's nothing to be worried about.